# How to minimize this mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

whole day i'm trying to put all this query in one, but nothing work, pls help
I need to update count if asset_id exist in array, or insert {asset_id: id, count: 1} if not
here is array

```
{
 from: '1', 
 to: '2', 
 json:[
        {asset_id: id, count: 1},
        {asset_id: id, count: 1},
        {asset_id: id, count: 1}
 ]
}
```

and this is query

```
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            from: res[i].from,
            to: res[i].to,
          },
          update: {
            from: res[i].from,
            to: res[i].to,
          },
          upsert: true,
        },
      },
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            from: res[i].from,
            to: res[i].to,
            json: { $elemMatch: { asset_id: res[i].asset_id } },
          },
          update: {
            $inc: { "json.$.count": 1 },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        updateOne: {
          filter: {
            from: res[i].from,
            to: res[i].to,
            json: { $not: { $elemMatch: { asset_id: res[i].asset_id } } },
          },
          update: {
            $push: {
              json: { asset_id: res[i].asset_id, count: 1 },
            },
          },
          //upsert: true,
        },
      }
```

Comment: Is the order of the items in the array important?

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the array is not important you can do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      jsonWithOut: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$json", cond: {$ne: ["$$this.asset_id", dataToInsert.asset_id]}}
      },
      jsonOfNew: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$json", cond: {$eq: ["$$this.asset_id", dataToInsert.asset_id]}}
      },
      json: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {$set: {
      jsonOfNew: {
        $cond: [
          {$eq: [{$size: "$jsonOfNew"}, 0]},
          [dataToInsert],
          [
            {
              asset_id: "$dataToInsert.asset_id",
              count: {$add: [{$first: "$jsonOfNew.count"}, 1]}
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      dataToInsert: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {$set: {
      json: {$concatArrays: ["$jsonWithOut", "$jsonOfNew"]},
      jsonOfNew: "$$REMOVE",
      jsonWithOut: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oDSqHALRCob)